# Why isnt this map continuous

Tags: general-topology

I was given that the map $f:X \rightarrow Y$ is continuous if and only if $X=\bigcup U_\alpha$ for $U_\alpha$ open, and $f|_{U_\alpha} \rightarrow Y$ is continuous.

Why isn't this statement true if $U_{\alpha}$ are closed instead of open?

I feel like the best way to show this would be to find a map $f:\mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ such that $\mathbb{R}=\bigcup C_\alpha$ for a countable collection of closed sets $C_\alpha$ where $f|C_\alpha$ is continuous but $f$ is not.  Unfortunately, I am stumped at this point.

The only solution I could think of was letting $C_x=\{x\}$ but this seems like a trivial solution

Comment: What' your problem with your trivial answer?

Comment: Countability is not assumed in your statement anyway

Comment: If you want a countable counter-example where $X = Y = \Bbb{R}$, take $f(x) = -1$ for $x \le 0$ and $f(x) = 1$ for $x > 0$. Then take $U_0 = (-\infty, 0]$ and $U_n = [1/n, \infty)$.

Answer (score 1):

As @Arctic Char points out, your "trivial solution" is a fine idea. Any function from a one-point space is continuous, and any space $X$ can obviously be covered by one-point spaces. So any function from $X$ is continuous when restricted to all of those $C_x$; but not any function from $X$ is continuous.